# finding Minimum value based on a range of values in another column in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
10.00   b1
11.00   b2
22.00   b3
2.00    b1
323.00  b2
1.00    b3
423.00  b1
32.00   b2
42.00   b3
43.00   b1
522.00  b2
53.00   b3
22.00   b1
344.00  b2
33.00   b3
23445.00    b1
323.00  b2
4.00    b3
```

How can I find the minimum value of column1 where value of column2 = b2?

Comment: Perhaps you could sort them ascending?

Comment: you can find the answer to this in probably every tutorial and on many many other sites through a web search.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I got one for you. It is an excel formula.

```
=MIN(IF(B1:B100="b2",A1:A100))
```